# Free scroll pane (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, pane

What pane can I use to add anchorpanes(setting y and z). 
Initially it is of a certain size, and if it is too many anchorpanes to show, i`d like to add a scroller with which I can scroll down the pane to see more elements.

P.S.
sry for my bad english

Comment: Can't you use a [`ScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html)? I think you can add `AnchorPane`s to it, but I am not sure...

Comment: What is the problem not to use ScrollPane?

Comment: scrollpane is not exactly that i want, i can`t set x & y for the elements, or mb i don`t know something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Question is very simple to answer. Just use a Scroll Pane and a Element to group your Anchor-Panes, for example :
[ScrollPane with VBox as Grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S23zI.png)

Or you can also use Frameworks for this like :

http://www.jfoenix.com/

http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/

When I remember correctly, they designed a Pane which is automatically placing nodes like a Gallery. These nodes get moved when necessary.

Comment: And if you want to set the x & y, just use another Anchor Pane for Grouping. Cheers